# Room, один Entity для нескольких таблиц

Tags: java, sql, android-room

Как реализовать чтобы один enitry (Model) имел две таблицы в бд?

```
@Entity(
        tableName = "trash"
)
public class TrashNote {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;

    private String title;
    private String value;
    private long date;
    private String type;

    @Ignore
    private boolean Checked;

    public TrashNote create(String title, String value, long date, String type) {
        this.title = title;
        this.value = value;
        this.date = date;
        this.type = type;
        this.Checked = false;
        return this;
    }

    public TrashNote create(String title, String value, int date) {
        this.title = title;
        this.value = value;
        this.date = date;
        this.type = "note";
        return this;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public boolean getChecked() {
        return this.Checked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean arg) {
        this.Checked = arg;
    }

    public long getDate() {
        return this.date;
    }

    public void setDate(long date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return this.type;
    }

}
```

Comment: Одна таблица - один entity. Сделай два класса, если они имеют схожие поля, то сделай базовый класс и два класса наследника

Comment: @DanilApsadikov, у меня проблема в том что: у меня есть две активности которые используют один класс для работы класса нужен адаптер, у каждой активности разные адаптеры из-за то что разные таблицы.

Comment: Сделай generic adapter (параметризованный класс)

Comment: @DanilApsadikov, у меня используеться DiffUtil, из-за него куча ошибок

Comment: Ты можешь сделать параметризованный  DiffUtil и Adapter. У тебя есть базовая Entity, DiffUtil и Adapter параметризованные и работают с классами, которые наследуют базовую entity

Comment: @DanilApsadikov, ваше решение мне помогло! никогда не слышал об этом адаптере, спасибо что дали направление куда копать))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения это вопроса я использовал **generic adapter (параметризованный класс)**